# How to display vertical and horizontal headers in p:datatable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to display a table that has both vertical and horizontal headers with JSF 2.1.7 and Primefaces 3.3.1.

This is basically what I would like to do:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Hor 1</th>
            <th>Hor 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <th>vert 1</th>
            <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>vert 2</th>
            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the best I managed to achieve:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{ctrl.values}" var="val">
    <p:column styleClass="ui-state-default">
        <h:outputText value="Vertical header" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Horizontal header">
        <h:outputText value="#{val.anything}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The ui class styles my cell as a header, that's enough for me (no row selecting or filtering). But I've still got a problem: the header text that should replace "Vertical header" in this example comes from a resource bundle that's accessed through EL. How can I define which values will be displayed for each row?

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "standard" way of adding headers (and footers) to data tables and columns in JSF. This works for standard and PrimeFaces components. You have to add a facet with the name `header` (or `footer`) to `p:dataTable` or `p:column` - depending if you want to have a header (or footer) for the table itself or the column.

With PrimeFaces it is even simpler for columns. Just add the attribute `headerText` (or `footerText` on `p:column`.

See the following example:

```
<p:dataTable var="person" value="#{bean.persons}">  
  <f:facet name="header">  
    Persons  
  </f:facet>  
  <p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">  
      Name
    </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="#{person.name}"/>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Email">  
    <h:outputText value="#{person.email}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

BUT, I do not know if it is possible to add "headers" for rows.

Please see the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) or the [PrimeFaces 3.3 user guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf) for further details.

If you need different texts coming from a resource bundle in every row, I would load the texts in Java code and add them to the objects that are displayed in the data table. Simply create a new class that extends/delgates to/proxies the original class you intended to display and add a property `headerLabel` (value coming from the resource bundle). Then you can do something like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="person" value="#{bean.personsWithLabels}">  
  <p:column>  
    <h:outputText value="#{person.headerLabel}"/>
  </p:column>
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```